# Calculate DateAdd in aggregation SQL subquery in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, subquery, aggregation, dateadd

I created a subquery inside my select statement which aggregates multiple columns into one which then is called `[maxBoosterDatum]`. Now I need to perform a `DateAdd` calculation with the result of the calculated value. Can anyone please help/advise me on how I can achieve this?

```
(SELECT MAX(maxBoosterDatum) 
 FROM (VALUES (Quests.[Datum Booster Impfung]), 
              (Quests.[Datum Booster Impfung nach 1]), 
              (Quests.[Datum Booster Impfung nach 2])) AS DatumB(maxBoosterDatum)) AS maxBoosterDatum,
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: example `DATEADD( DAY, 1, MAX(maxBoosterDatum) )`

Comment: What's *stopping* you using `DATEADD` against the subquery you have, exactly?

Comment: @Larnu Goddamn, I'm so stupid! You are absolutely right. I just had to put the dateadd infront of the subquery. Somehow my brain didn't want to think this straightforward. Now i just have to figure out how to convert the nvarchar type into datetime without the nulls

Comment: So are your 3 columns, in the above, all `nvarchar` data types, @MarcoMikuš ? That is a design flaw, and you really should be fixing your design to store your date and time values as a [date and time data type](//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql#DateandTimeDataTypes). Note, as well, if your value isn't stored in something like the format `yyyyMMdd` then the `MAX` value likely isn't what you expect. `N'06/06/2022'` is **before** `N'17/01/2019'`, not after.

Comment: @Larnu yes I agree with you that this is my database design flaw. The thing is that other developers created for our clinical study an online questionnaire, and from their program, I download a CSV File and update with it my database. In this Data, there were some initial parser issues and I didn't want to lose the data when I import it into my database, therefore the quickest solution for me was to use nvarchar and then deal with it later when I clean the data. Maybe at this point, this is the right time for me to figure out a way to unify it to date/time or create a if/then statement.